# Canvas page URL Errors

Tags: facebook, web-applications, facebook-graph-api, facebook-canvas

I've made numerous Facebook apps and attached them to fan pages no problem but for some reason I can never access the apps via the canvas page directly.

For example: https://apps.facebook.com/cashcallwatch/

is coming back with a URL errors, absolutely no idea why. I've looked all over for a solution / explanation but havent been able to figure it out. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the Page Tab iframe you will see that it points to: https://www.cashcall.tv/CashCallFacebook/

That url is to a directory, you probably want to change the Page tab url to any of your php/html documents, for example: https://www.cashcall.tv/CashCallFacebook/facebookwatchandwin.php

If you can't point directly to a document, just rename facebookwatchandwin.php to index.php and it will probably work since it will be served as the default document for that directory.